# Best way to compare object variables and look for changes

Tags: vb.net, variables, object, compare

I have a function that will be passed an object that contains MANY variables. These variables all get stored in a database. Later a new object will be passed to my function and most of the time it will be identical. But sometimes one or two variables will be different and I'll have to take various actions based on those changes. Other than looping through every variable and comparing it to every stored version of that variable, how might I do this? Can I some how generate a hash value for an entire object? Since the object will be the same most if the times it is passed to me this would be a quick way to determine that nothing has changed.

Comment: Are you implementing your own ORM?  If not, you could probably find the answer in the source of an open-source ORM.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that you store all variables in database, so I think you should make database calls as few as possible. In order to that, you can write a stored procedure that is called when a row is inserted into the table that holds your values. In this procedure you can calculate a hash value and update a column in the table that is added to store hash values. You may use `sys.dbms_crypto.hash` function in Oracle to calculate a hash value. When you need to search an object if it is there, again call a stored procedure that inputs a text value of your current objects values, creates a hash value again with the same function and calls select statement and if a row returns, it returns "Y" otherwise "N". You may add index to the "hash value column" to make things faster.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably consume as many, if not more, resources trying to determine whether or not anything has changed. Unless you are receiving hundreds of thousands of requests per hour, then it is probably just as easy to update the database with the record each time.